# How to ensure closing of a connection at the end of the program

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-httpclient-4.x, finalizer

I connect to a DB using a [CloseableHttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html). I use this connection to query the DB and at the end of the program I want to ensure that I log out and close the connection.

Where in the code should I logout and close the `CloseableHttpClient`? If I don't do that the session is kept open in the DB.

The most appropriate place would be in a `finalize` method, but there is no guarantee that it will be called before the program terminates. And if it terminates without explicitly logging out, there will be a stale connection, which I want to avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If your program will be killed for ex. with the task manager you can't do anythig. So the best method is to use the `finalize` method